# How to delete all entires in a table that are not included in a list

Tags: sql, sqlite

For a simple example I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
   personID INTEGER,
   name TEXT
);
```

Now I have a list (array) of names, for example `[Peter, Nicolas, Alex]`. I need to delete all entires that are not in the list. What is the best (performance wise) sql query to do so?

Comment: SQLite has no type called "array", so your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do fine:

```
delete from persons
where name not in ('Peter', 'Nicolas', 'Alex')
```

Answer (score 0):

for more generic code use left join like bellow:

```
delete Persons
from Persons p
left join yourArray
  on p.name = yourArray.id
where yourArray.id is null
```